# Python - sklearn.MLPClassifier: How to obtain output of the first hidden layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was going through some deep learning techniques and came across a method that does not use back-propagation (https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02480). The basic idea of this method is to train the shallow single hidden layer, discard the output layer, and add another hidden layer between the trained (first) hidden layer and a new output layer. The process is repeated (adding and training) until some criterion is met. 
I'm trying to implement this method using the MLP classifier provided in sklearn. The problem I'm facing is how to obtain the output of the hidden layers. For example, if I use

```
mlp = MLPClassifier()
mlp.predict(data)
```

, it will give me the output of the entire network. However, what I require is the sub-output of the hidden layer of the network. To illustrate:

input --> connection1 (weights) --> hidden layer --> connection2 (weights) --> output (--> prediction)

What I currently require is not the output prediction but the result that comes out of the hidden layer (between the hidden layer and connection 2).
I'm aware that the input for the hidden layer (between connection1 and hidden layer) can be calculated by

```
np.matmul(data, mlp.coefs_[0]) + mlp.intercepts_[0]
```

Is there a way to obtain the results of the hidden layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misunderstood what is what.

The input is what you pass in.

The first hidden layer is comprised of model parameters W<sub>1</sub> and b<sub>1</sub>.

The output of the hidden layer is f(W<sub>1</sub><sup>T</sup>x + b<sub>1</sub>) where `f` is your activation function.

This is then the input to the second hidden layer which is comprised of model parameters W<sub>2</sub> and b<sub>2</sub>. And so it goes....

So, to be precise

```
from sklearn.neural_network._base import ACTIVATIONS
ACTIVATIONS['relu'](np.matmul(data, mlp.coefs_[0]) + mlp.intercepts_[0]))
```

is what you're looking for.

Comment: So I guess I was halfway there after all. Is there a way to access the activation function defined for the sklearn mlp classifier? mlp.activation just gives a string of that is defined for the parameter. Or do I have to define it manually?

Comment: @CodyChung See the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html). It's ReLU by default. You can specify any one of {‘identity’, ‘logistic’, ‘tanh’, ‘relu’}.

Comment: Oh, as I said, I knew how to access what is 'defined' as the activation function (it is indeed relu), however, I was wonder if there is a way to actually use the function without manually defining it?

Comment: @CodyChung you don't manually define it, it's already defined in sklearn, you just specify what you want to use. Or am I misunderstanding you because I don't get the point of your question? If you're asking whether you can pass your own activation function, then I'm not sure (I don't think you can).

Comment: Sorry about that, I couldn't find the activation function in the classifier class. It was in the ._base module.

Comment: shouldn't it be `from sklearn.neural_network._base import ACTIVATIONS; ACTIVATIONS['relu'](np.matmul(data, mlp.coefs_[0]) + mlp.intercepts_[0]))` ?

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles on this answer like I did, the ACTIVATIONS dictionary functions are now all in place. Relu is just numpy.maximum(0, X) though.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else scrolling by looking for the deepest hidden layer...

```
def deepest_layer(data, MLP, layer=0):
    L = ACTIVATIONS['relu'](np.matmul(data, MLP.coefs_[layer]) + MLP.intercepts_[layer])
    layer += 1
    if layer >= len(MLP.coefs_)-1:
        return L
    else:
        return deepest_layer(L, MLP, layer=layer)

L = deepest_layer(data, mlp)
```

Comment: Great function, but ACTIVATIONS['relu'] now returns None. You can define the old function as def relu(X): return np.maximum(0, X)